# how to align vector (deleted double quotes) and print out in c++ after reading a txt file?

Tags: c++

I have a txt file includes strings, int, and float. I use a vector to store them.
The file can be read and print out. But the vector is not aligned and the double quotes also have not deleted.

These are my codes:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "assignment1.h"

using namespace std;

vector <assignment1*> rsult;

assignment1* parseLine(std::string str)
{
    vector<string>store;
    string tok = "";
    assignment1* retv = nullptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)str.size(); i++)
    {
        char c = str[i];
        if (c != ',')
        {
            tok = tok + c;
        }
        else
        {
            store.push_back(tok);
            tok = "";
        }
    }
    if (tok != "") { store.push_back(tok); }
    
    retv = new assignment1(store[0], store[1], store[2], store[3], store[4], store[5], store[6]);

    //id=store[0]
    //name=store[1]
    //postcode=store[2]
    //city=store[3]
    //purchases=store[4]
    //returns=store[5]
    //cIDs=store[6]

    return retv;
}

bool readFile()
{

    std::ifstream myFile("Data1.txt");
    if (!myFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "It failed to open the file" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::string str;

    int i = 0;
    while (std::getline(myFile, str))
    {
        //cout << "DEBUG -- line " << ++i << " is:" << str << endl;
        if (str[0] != '/')
        {
            assignment1* assignment1 = parseLine(str);
            rsult.push_back(assignment1);
        }
    }

    for (assignment1* t : rsult)
    {
        t->show();
    }

    return true;
}

void assignment1::show()
{
    cout << id << setw(10) << name << setw(10) << postcode << setw(10) << city << setw(10) << purchases << setw(10) << returns << setw(10) << cIDs << endl;
}
```

The file looks like this:

```
U2123,Sam Inc,2006, lyons,"21,600.00",13.10,123
A721,Merry Inc,2604, Kingston,"21,600.10",103.00,
U2122,Pippin Inc,2612, reid,"21,600.00",0
```

The result I print out looks like this:

```
U2123   Sam Inc      2006     lyons       "21   600.00"     13.10
A721 Merry Inc      2604  Kingston       "21   600.10"    103.00
U2122Pippin Inc      2612      reid       "21   600.00"         0
```

The result I want is this:

```
U2123     Sam Inc      2006     lyons       21    600.00     13.10
A721    Merry Inc      2604  Kingston       21    600.10    103.00
U2122  Pippin Inc      2612      reid       21    600.00         0
```

Comment: Problem one is that your CSV parser (`parse_line`) needs to be able to handle double quotes.  You must ignore commas that occur within double quotes,  That means adding an additional state variable that says whether you are inside quotes or not.

Comment: Because the result you show that you want is surely not what you really want.  You want the "21,600.00" to be displayed as a single column.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [what is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: When you tokenize the row you need to handle quotes and ignore commas that occur inside quotes. You can do this by reading the line and then reading char by char, if you find a quote handle any subsequent commas as part of the string then when next quote is found resume breaking on commas.